# Jmeter with Apache Ant - command prompt/HTML output NaN

Tags: jmeter

I have followed those steps, to set up Jmeter in my local machine:

```
OS          - Windows 7
Java        - JDK jdk1.7.0_55
Jmeter      - 2.11
Apache Ant  - apache-ant-1.9.4
```

Environment Variable set:
Under System Variable

```
   1. Variable NAME  - ANT_HOME
      Variable Value - D:\apache-ant-1.9.4

      in PATH variable - D:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;D:\apache-ant-1.9.4\lib;          

   2. Variable NAME  - JAVA_HOME
      Variable Value - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

      in PATH variable - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin; 

   3. Variable NAME  - JMETER_HOME
      Variable Value - %JMETER_HOME%\lib;
```

Using [this link](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) Jmeter with Apache Ant configured using Apache task.

While running Jmeter in Non-Gui Mode:

```
      D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin>jmeter -n -t ThreadGroup.jmx -l Test.jtl
```

Following output gots,

```
   Creating summariser <summary>
   Created the tree successfully using ThreadGroup.jmx
   Starting the test @ Fri May 30 10:41:13 IST 2014 (1401426673073)
   Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
   summary =      0 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0 Err:
   0 (0.00%)
 Tidying up ...    @ Fri May 30 10:41:13 IST 2014 (1401426673949)
  ... end of run
```

in HTML output : `NaN`

I spent a lot time to find a solution. They have mentioned to change the java version and plus to include xalan/serializer in apache-ant/lib folder.
After doing this, have I to make any changes in apache-jmeter-2.11 build.xml?

What changes i should follow in build.xml?

In build.xml, i found a line

```
  <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
```

what is this?

Please help me out to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that both `xalan-*.jar` and `serializer-*.jar` are present in `$JMETER_HOME/lib/`.
2. In build.xml used along with jmeter-ant-task if you have `xslt.classpath` defined as

```
<!-- 
 | Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ 
 +-->
<path id="xslt.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
</path>
```

then ensure that your `xslt-report` report target defined in the same build.xml uses it:

```
<target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
    . . .
    <xslt
        classpathref="xslt.classpath"
        . . .
    </xslt>
</target>
```

i.e.

```
classpathref="xslt.classpath"
```

---

As well

```
Variable NAME  - JMETER_HOME
Variable Value - %JMETER_HOME%\lib;
```

looks quite oddly.
`JMETER_HOME` should point to jmeter's root dir, not to /lib.

Comment: Hi,D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras>ant
Buildfile: D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\build.xml:152: D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\${jmete
r.lib} does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: JMETER_HOME/bin.my build.xml in JMETER_HOME/extras looks like                     <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/><!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent Java 1.4+ -->
<path id="xslt.classpath"<filesetdir="${jmeter.lib}"includes="xalan*.jar"/><fileset dir="${jmeter.lib}" includes="serializer*.jar"/></path>what am doing wrong? D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras>ant
Buildfile: D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\build.xml:152: D:\apache-jmeter-2.11\extras\${jmete
r.lib} does not exist.
Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: Well, replace ${jmeter.lib} with ${lib.dir} as in original build.xml (fixed in answer above) and try again. ${jmeter.lib} is custom equivalent for ${lib.dir} I've defined manually.

Comment: <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
        
    </path> what to change ? please change it ?